# How to check date is leading with zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How to check whether the given date has leading zero or not?

Actually i am getting the date in parameter and i need to check if the date contains leading zero then i should remove the zero and carry on the process.

Example.

```
string stringdate = Page.RouteData.Values["date"].ToString();
```

Here the Examples of "date" could be

3-May-2013  (OR) 03-May-2013

if the stringdate of secondtype(starting with Zero) then i should remove the zero and make it like first type and carry on the process.

I tried below work

```
bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(stringdate, "dd-MMMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed);
```

but if the 'date' value is '16-December-2013' then i end up with issue as it returns true.

So how to check whether 'Date' start with Zero or not?

Comment: @MUGAN: Stupid question? hmm why don't you provide me the solution after reading the question?  i have asked how to check whether date has leading Zero or not and not remove. Can you help me?

Comment: what is the reason you need the 'Date' start with Zero or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the leading zero before processing if it exist

```
if(stringdate[0] == '0')
    stringdate = stringdate.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Oh...This was simple solution. :-) Thanks...I kept banging my head with the different date formats. Thanks again.

Comment: and i can remove the leading Zero with 'd-MMMM-yyyy' but i was just wondering how to test whether the date has Zero or not at starting.

Comment: better if u use string.StartsWith, rather than accessing the element through index, it would give an exception if `stringdate` contains empty string.

Answer (score 1):

> So how to check whether 'Date' start with Zero or not?

You don't have to. If parsing is the only issue then instead of format `"dd-MMMM-yyyy"` you should use `"d-MMMM-yyyy"`, since single `d` would work for both, single / double digit day part.  With the above format  you can parse `03` or `3` day. You can look at [Custom Date and Time format string- MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

**EDIT:**

If you only want to check if the date string starts with `0` then use [`string.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) method.

```
if(stringdate.StartsWith("0"))
    stringdate = stringdate.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Yes Parasing issue and i have tried "d-MMMM-yyyy" and it results true for "07-December-2012" which is wrong for my case.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan, you can use `string.StartsWith` to compare for `0` and then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need in the end is to get the string value without a leading zero, you can use the *d-MMMM-yyyy* format string both for parsing and formatting:

```
string stringDate = "03-May-2013";
DateTime parsedDate;
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    stringDate,
    "d-MMMM-yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out parsedDate);
if (isValid)
{
    stringDate = parsedDate.ToString("d-MMMM-yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Can you please try for "16-March-2013"? For this value also it will enter inside "If" statement. right? I want to check whether date is leading with Zero or not. If leading with Zero then enter 'if' condition.